# Conditional loading of dynamic PHP content based on UA

Tags: javascript, browser, user-agent, modernizr

I am developing a WordPress theme that uses a custom Walker class to generate the primary navigation menu. The primary menu has lots of photographs, you can think of it similarly to [UberMenu](http://wpmegamenu.com/).

I obviously do not want to load all of these images on mobile devices, and instead want just a basic text menu if you will.

I want to load the correct menu depending on the UA and/or users screen size. Is it possible to conditionally load which menu I want to use (using javascript?), before all the images are loaded to the browser. I do not want to load both menus and then hide one depending on screen size, as the browser will still have to load all of the images in the background.

I was thinking of placing the `wp_nav_menu()` function in a separate PHP file, and then loading that PHP depending on the screen size, but I am not sure if this is safe and/or efficient or the right way to do this. I am using Modernizr if it helps.

Any ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think detecting the user agent and deciding what content to serve is best done on the server side, but this is a charged debate with strong points on either side.

To do it with PHP, this code with the [mobile detect library](http://mobiledetect.net) would get the job done:

```
<?php
require_once 'Mobile_Detect.php';
$detect = new Mobile_Detect;
if ( $detect->isMobile() || $detect->isTablet() ) {
    // mobile code
} else {
    // desktop code
}
?>
```

To do it with front-end code, you can go [full responsive](http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design), involving CSS and media queries, or use this for simple conditional logic:

```
if ( Modernizr.touch ) {
    // mobile code
} else {
    // desktop code
}
```